# CSS Responsive Design Order of Columns

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Ok, I have 3 columns floating left. Now when the viewport is less than 600px I want column 2 to appear before column 1 without using `position:absolute`. Is there a way to do this just by using CSS and HTML?

If not you can also post other variants.

[Here's my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mKbnH/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/dWJ9g/

You will see I've reordered the col1 and col2 in the HTML and applied margin to the #col1 and #col2

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">HEADER</div>
<div id="main">
     <div id="col2" class="cols">COL 2</div>
    <div id="col1" class="cols">COL 1</div>

    <div id="col3" class="cols">COL 3</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer" class="clear">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

CSS changes

```
#col1 {float:left; height:100px; width:200px; background:#cc4444;margin-left:-400px;}
#col2 {float:left; height:200px; width:200px; background:#44cc44;margin-left:200px;}  


@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
#wrapper, #header, #main, #footer {width:100%;}
#col1, #col2, #col3 {float:none; width:100%;margin-left:0;}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is awesome. I didn't think of using negative margin.

Comment: If this technique works for you in practice, it may give a small SEO boost as well. If the main page content is in col 2, and col 1 is a menu or secondary content, then moving the HTML for col 2 higher on the page will give it a little more weight with search engines as well.

Comment: Thanks David, you really helped me out!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the markup I'd suggest using javascript, to change the html and id.

http://jsfiddle.net/FBAtT/

```
var col1 = document.getElementById('col1'),
    col2 = document.getElementById('col2'),
    swapped = false;

window.onresize = function () {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width < 600 && swapped === false) {
        swapCols();
        swapped = true;
    } else if (width > 600 && swapped === true) {
        swapCols();
        swapped = false;
    }
};

function swapCols() {
    var _col1 = col1.innerHTML,
        _col1id = col1.id,
        _col2 = col2.innerHTML,
        _col2id = col2.id;
    col1.innerHTML = _col2;
    col1.id = _col2id;
    col2.innerHTML = _col1;
    col2.id = _col1id;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. it works fine but i wanted to use pure css and html.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/mKbnH/2/

CSS

```
html * {margin:0; padding:0;}
body {background:#000; font-family:helvetica, verdana;}
#wrapper {margin:50px auto;}
#wrapper, #header, #main, #footer {width:600px;}
#header {height:100px; background:#cccc44;}
#main {}
#col1 {float:left; height:100px; width:200px; background:#cc4444;}
#col2 {float:left; height:200px; width:200px; background:#44cc44;}
#col3 {float:left; height:150px; width:200px; background:#4444cc;}
#footer {height:50px; background:#cc44cc;}

.cols {}
.clear {clear:both;}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
    #wrapper, #header, #main, #footer {width:100%;}
    #col3 {width:100%;}
    #col1, #col2 {width:50%}
}
```

Comment: sry, but it behaves different